# How to style Text input in jQuery editable

Tags: jquery, css, jeditable, textinput

I have to customize perfectly the Text Input in my [Table](http://tommywebdesigner.com/jeditable/email.html) made with jQuery editable.

If you look up [here](http://tommywebdesigner.com/jeditable/email.html) and you click on **Wordpress Design** you can edit the text in the text Input created. My problem is that once i click on the **Wordpress Design** the Text Input does not keep fixed  as the Text Area editable in **Concepto**. In fact if you click on **Concepto** you get a text area but the Text area in this case keeps fixed and does not move down as the Text Input in Wordpress Design.

Probably this is depending on how i am configuryng the CSS

This is the CSS code of the text input on **Wordpress Design title**

```
.editable_text_titulo input { font-size: 25px; }
```

What i need to do to get a Text Input editable fixed as the Text Area editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `h2.editable_text_titulo` `margin` and provide the `line-height:1em`;

like

```
h2.editable_text_titulo {
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0;
}
```